# Can't find serviceWorker in navigator anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

since the new update of Google Chrome (version 69.0.3497.92 (official build) (64-bit)) I can't find the serviceWorker service in the Navigator anymore. Actually I could register my Service Worker as follows but now I get an error that serviceWorker cannot be found in the navigator:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    /*
    *
    * Register the Service Worker
    *
    * */
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Service Worker Registered');
    });

} else console.log('Your browser does not support the Service-Worker!');
```

How can I now use the Service Worker again, or how can I get it to run again for all Chrome versions?

Comment: Thanks for this.  I totally forgot about the req for https also and couldn't figure out why my first site worked (https) and my other wasn't (http). That's a couple hours I'll never get back.  

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Serve your page over HTTPS or use `localhost`. Service workers [require](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#navigator-serviceworker) a [Secure Context](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/).

([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts), [Chromium page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)).

The value of `window.isSecureContext` indicates whether `[SecureContext]` features are visible or hidden. (This is `true` on a `file://` URL and the serviceWorker API will be visible, but it won't work, of course.)

Comment: Ohw yes you're absolutely right. I tried to access the Service Worker via the local IP. With localhost it works again.

Comment: Does anyone know how to allow this on Virtual Hosts on my local dev machine? I have several projects under different .test domains pointing to my local dev machine. So I'm on localhost only Chrome doesn't see it. Or should I use another TLD?

Answer (score 132):

If you are using a virtual host locally for a domain other than localhost, you can tell chrome to treat your custom domain as "secure".

In the addressbar: `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

Then add your domain like `http://my-local-dev-domain.test`

Click enable and click the restart button.

Comment: perfect for me! Thank you

Comment: Perfect answer for me too

Answer (score 5):

Another reason might be running a browser in private-mode

Comment: Kindly check question and ask this again as the given information is not sufficient to understand and answer back.

Comment: Hi meydlo. Please read [answer] and try to [edit] this into a clear and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

insteade http://**192.168.1.105**:8080/ go to http://**localhost**:8080/
it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to your vscode settings in the user>Extension option scroll down to live server config

set your host to localhost --ScreenShot
[Set host to local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUDAJ.png)

Now scroll down and uncheck use local IP option -- ScreenShot [uncheck localIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQzRE.png)

go to your Port json setting and set the port to 8080 --ScreenShot [json setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AohYs.png)
[set port to 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if9wO.png)
Go live and check console