# Cannot read property 'register' of undefined service worker Nuxt JS

Tags: vuejs2, service-worker, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement a custom built service worker into my Nuxt JS site. I'm getting an error after generating the site as follows:

```
Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
```

```
function Notify (siteOptions) {
  /* Set Dependancies */
  this.siteOptions = siteOptions /* Register Applicant */
  this.register()
} /** * Register Service Worker */
Notify.prototype.register = function () {
  /** * Test Registration */
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('Notify-service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {
    console.log('SW: Available')
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error('SW: Not Available', error)
  })
```

It appears that this is the line causing issues:

`navigator.serviceWorker.register('Notify-service-worker.js')`

Comment: Serve your page over HTTPS or use localhost. Service workers require a Secure Context. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300901/194717

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [best practice](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration) to check whether service workers are supported in the current browser prior to registering:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
         window.addEventListener('load', function () {
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
         });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that service workers work only on https. I solved it by using "Localhost:3000" in the address instead of the IP.

Otherwise, you can go to chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure and click on enabled and add the application localhost link!