# Django and navigator.serviceWorker.register is working only localhost

Tags: javascript, django

In my project I have such line of code

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('{% static "js/firebase-messaging-sw.js" %}')
```

But if I launch my project not on localhost, I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`

Comment: are you still trying to access static files on develepment server? Can you access on js/firebase-messaging-sw.js on browser? I think it is static file issue

Comment: @marlonjd - yes, I can access this file

Comment: Can you check on developer console on browser. On network tab it will show. Which address this trying to access ? It will show 404, 200 or 500.

Comment: @marlonjd - I can't see such response on network tab. Maybe because my script is in html body?

Comment: On localhost, can you see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to serve page over HTTPS or use localhost. Service workers require a Secure Context.

Here is the link to [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300901/5594008)