# navigator.serviceWorker always undefined on mobile Chrome and mobile Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, ios, service-worker, mobile-chrome

I'm seeing `navigator.serviceWorker` always return `undefined` in mobile Chrome and mobile Firefox on both iOS and Android devices. The site is being served over HTTPS, `window.isSecureContext` returns `true`, and I'm not in a private/incognito window/tab. This rules out common explanations for this, such as those [pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299246/cant-find-serviceworker-in-navigator-anymore).

It would seem these mobile browsers simply do not support the ServiceWorker API, but from everything I've seen they should.

Any ideas?

Comment: iOS pseudo browsers are not real browsers, they just use a WebView to allow sharing your passwords, favorites, etc.
However the latest iOS (14) should allow WebViews to finally use service workers. But right now I think that is limited to a developer preview of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

For the iOS case, I upgraded iOS from 13.x to the (super recent) 14.x. I was already on the latest versions of both Firefox and Chrome, so perhaps those upgrades required the latest iOS (not sure). As to why they weren't working on Android, I believe the problem was related to a different issue.

Anyways, perhaps this is helpful for someone else who may hit this. Mobile Firefox and mobile Chrome on both iOS and Android certainly support service workers.