# How to solve Service worker is not Supported by browser after hosted on IIS?

Tags: reactjs

I host  reactjs pwa app on IIS Server.I got error as Service worker is not Supported by browser

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EO0z.png)

Comment: The error clearly explains the problem is the browser, not IIS. Which browser and version are you using? Chrome for example doesn't allow unsecured service worker connections, making an exception for localhost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service worker is not supported in chrome (69.0.3497.81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269746/service-worker-is-not-supported-in-chrome-69-0-3497-81)

Comment: BTW you shouldn't be using HTTP in the first place. Most web projects redirect to https out of the box. How did you create the react application?

Comment: when i hit this url " https://localhost:8080/ " on another pcs that time i can not browse that site, its only run local machine using which i hosted site.

Comment: That's what `localhost` means - connect to the *local* host/machine. Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome needs service workers to be served over https (secure communication), but allows an exception for localhost for development. 
you can add your local address to Chrome by copy pasting below line to your chrome's address bar 
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
and then add your IP address there, select  enable from right hand side drop down and restart.